# returning a link with onclick embeded within a php function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to return a link with an onclick function but I think I am getting my quotations confused because the link wont work.

here is the code:

```
return "<a class='link_to_member' onClick='window.location.href='page_detail.php?page=$item_id';'>$item_name</a>";
```

Comment: What about this? `return "<a class='link_to_member' onClick='window.location.href=\"page_detail.php?page=$item_id\"'>$item_name</a>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always escape quotes by putting an escape character `\` before them.

```
return "<a class='link_to_member' onClick='window.location.href=\"page_detail.php?page=$item_id\";'>$item_name</a>";
```

Comment: Yup your right! These subtle nuances between languages are killing me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should escape inner single quote.

```
    return "<a class='link_to_member' 
          onClick='window.location.href=\'page_detail.php?page=$item_id\';'>
           $item_name
   </a>";
```